# Run a React Native iOS release build from terminal

Tags: ios, react-native, react-native-cli

I am trying to run the release build directly from the terminal and I did not found an option to do that.

From XCode what is required to do is:

> Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme (cmd + <), make sure you're in the
>   Run tab from the side, and set the Build Configuration dropdown to
>   release.

http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device-ios.html#building-your-app-for-production

There is any option available from the `react-native-cli` to do the same? Something like `react-native run-ios -configuration Release`?

My objective is to generate a build that does not require the server being running to provide to the QA team for instance.

Answer (score 144, accepted):

I did a PR to the React Native project to allow this feature. The PR can be check here: https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/ca7cbdee858e84c4a74a2d9c7be151f5cfdcfbfe

So, in the future, to run a release build from terminal you just only need to type the following command: `npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release`

If you want run your project on a real device use `--device` parameter:

```
npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release --device "Your Device Name"
```

Comment: Thanks. Need to upgrade to v0.39+ though.

Comment: Thanks so much for this PR, can you please add some more words on this subject. I was able to release to Android easily following this - https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/signed-apk-android.html - however after I run `react-native run-ios --configuration Release` I don't know what to do :( I can't even find the binary it created so I can install it on my device. :( I was avoiding fastlane as I wanted to learn the manual way for my first time.

Comment: Hum, to generate the binary to upload to AppStore/ install in your device you need to do the following: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42130914/3482000

Comment: For me it runs it on emulator. How can I target my device?

Comment: what file is outputted by this command which can be uploaded to the app store?

Comment: Doesn't work. `An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):`

Comment: @pborbas use `--device` parameter.

Answer (score 19):

## May 2023

Just an update: **configuration** has been deprecated in favor of **mode**.

`npx react-native run-ios --mode Release`

Comment: This should be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3):

Checked right now, and it works:

`npx react-native run-ios --configuration Release --simulator="iPhone 14"`

Answer (score 1):

Simple and easy just run the command

```
npx react-native run-ios --mode Release
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me:

```
npx react-native run-ios --mode Release --udid <Please enter your UDID>
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, react native doesn't come with something like that out-of-the-box.

But because your react-native app is also a plain Objective-C app with react-native on the inside, you can re-use existing tools to perform the build/packaging for you.

Check the following article for example on how to automate your build using [fastlane](https://fastlane.tools/).

https://shift.infinite.red/simple-react-native-ios-releases-4c28bb53a97b#.i1otlntat

Answer (score 0):

The react-native script that handles the bundling is here:

```
  ./node_modules/react-native/scripts/react-native-xcode.sh
```

and it basically does this:

```
  node "./node_modules/react-native/cli.js" bundle  --entry-file "index.js" --platform ios --dev false --reset-cache --bundle-output "./app.app/main.jsbundle" --assets-dest "./app.app"
```

where bundle-output and asset-dest would normally point to your xcode build output. For example:

```
~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MyApp-enjmlvtpwwpnsxanntxwgpneywcy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/ArchiveIntermediates/MyApp/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphonesimulator/MyApp.app
```