# How to build .ipa application for react-native-ios?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I would try "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41970435" But I'cant get .ipa file.

Can any one explain how to get the .ipa file?

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933439/how-to-build-react-native-ios-app-get-an-app-file-and-deploy-to-device

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build React Native iOS app, get an .app file and deploy to device?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34933439/how-to-build-react-native-ios-app-get-an-app-file-and-deploy-to-device)

Comment: This is not a duplicate of the above question because the answer on that question is out of date; the details have changed since the question was asked.

Comment: Possible deplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35476349/how-to-build-ipa-for-react-native

Answer (score 78, accepted):

1. Get the `.app` file:

   ```
    react-native run-ios --configuration=release
   ```
2. `.app` file path `Build/Products/Release/"<Your_Filename>.app"`.
3. Convert `.app` to `.ipa` :

   - Create folder `Payload`.
   - paste `.app` file into `Payload` folder.
   - compress the `Payload` folder.
   - change the name you want and put extension as `.ipa`.

Comment: Getting an error about provisioning profile and build size is 5 times large then Xcode build.

Comment: @RANVIRGORAI I didn't face issue like that. Could you attach your error dump .

Comment: Doesn't work. `An error was encountered processing the command (domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain, code=2):`

Comment: What is this witchcraft?

Comment: I got this error when I upload the ipa from transport "ERROR ITMS-90174: "Missing Provisioning Profile - Apps must contain a provisioning profile in a file named embedded.mobileprovision."

Comment: This Build/Products/Release/"<Your_Filename>.app" path does not exist. And what do you mean by Payload folder?

Comment: I can't find the Build folder to find Build/Products/Release/"<Your_Filename>.app". where to find?

Comment: @preston look at the CLI after running `react-native run-ios --configuration=release` if everything is fine you'll have the following line 

`info Installing "/Users/"<Your_Username>"/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/"<Your_Filename>"-gpyqutyfhaccnvgoneubfmtbglgw/Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/"<Your_Filename>".app"`

 that's the release.

But my question is that how do I compress Payload ? Is it a simple zip compression or another and specific one ?

Comment: @KhalilHamani yes, just compress, command line zip -r or UI normally. Change the extension .zip to .ipa in the file details.

Comment: on my system this command doesn't generate an .app file, it only starts the app in the iOS emulator (react-native 0.63.2)

Comment: when I open it in iPhone its opening as .zip file.

Comment: I followed all the steps and could upload the ipa to the device but when trying to start it I got a "This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified."

Answer (score 23):

- Delete localhost item from info.plist

  App transport security settings -> Exception domains
- Bundle ios

  ```
  react-native bundle --entry-file index.js --platform ios --dev false --bundle-output ios/main.jsbundle --assets-dest ios
  ```
- In Xcode

  Products->Scheme->Edit scheme -> Change build configuration to `RELEASE`
- In `AppDelegate.m`

  Replace

  ```
  jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  ```

  with

  ```
  #ifdef DEBUG
    jsCodeLocation = [[RCTBundleURLProvider sharedSettings] jsBundleURLForBundleRoot:@"index" fallbackResource:nil];
  #else
    jsCodeLocation = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"main" withExtension:@"jsbundle"];
  #endif
  ```
- Change device -> Generic iOS device
- Product -> Clean
- Product -> Build
- `.app` file can be found at

  ```
  ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/<app name>/Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/<appname>
  ```
- Create folder Payload.
- Paste `.app` file into Payload folder.
- Compress the Payload folder.
- Change the name you want and put extension as `.ipa`

Comment: After following these steps and successfully creating an ipa, I can no longer run the app in debug through the iOS simulator, any advice @aleena1995

Comment: Did you change Scheme to DEBUG and jsCodeLocation back to old one?@Arthur

Comment: Yeah I ended up reverting all the changes I had, is there a simple way to have both options and be able to bounce from debug and release builds? My current solution is to just keep debug, do all the changes for release, build, then revert

Comment: You can use the following code so that the jsCodeLocation will be selected depending on build configuration. Please check the updated solution @Arthur

Comment: @aleena1995 Is there any limitations to generating IPA this way? Will the app expire after a fixed amount of time?

Comment: It works, that's very nice. But when I run the ipa, I get the error "This app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified."

Answer (score 13):

You can run these commands in the ios directory.

```
xcodebuild clean archive -scheme <Scheme> -configuration Release -archivePath ../builds/<App>.xcarchive DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=<DevTeam> PROVISIONING_PROFILE=<PROVISIONING_PROFILE> CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY=<CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY>
xcodebuild -exportArchive -archivePath ../builds/<App>.xcarchive -exportPath ../builds/ -exportOptionsPlist ./iosExportOptions.plist
```

and iosExportOptions.plist can be something like

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
  <key>method</key>
  <string>app-store</string>
  <key>teamID</key>
  <string>{TEAM_ID}</string>
</dict>
</plist>
```

It is important to note that if you are using cocoapods then you need to build using the workspace and not the project. Adding this flag to the first command will make sure you are targeting the workspace `-workspace <AppName>.xcworkspace`.

You can also checkout fastlane. https://fastlane.tools/

OR

You can fill in all the details such as DEVELOPMENT_TEAM etc in Xcode and Product -> Archive
https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html

Comment: Is this the only way that we can export an IPA via Command Line? Or do we get any integrated command line option with react-native?

Comment: As of now, the options with react-native only build `.app` as pointed out by the other answer