# React native cant build .ipa file

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, react-native, macos-sierra

When I run :

```
react-native run-ios
```

everything works as expected, react native app runs everything as it should (had some troubles, adding react-native camera but editing info.plist / following the manual instructions, managed to get it to work)

Currently my goal is to get the .ipa file into an iPhone and try it out, but, following [How to build .ipa application for react-native-ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110496/how-to-build-ipa-application-for-react-native-ios) accepted answer, results in the app getting stuck on the itunes instalation (it says its installing but does nothing)

Other solution is to build .ipa from xcode, so I openned the ios project in xcode, but whenever I try to run it (even run it to emulator) it returns

```
"linker command failed with exit code 1"
```

in the "***Tests" app...

In summary : Can build app to emulator using react-native run-ios, can't get .ipa to install currectly on physical device

Comment: for building ipa from xcode (test app error), go to build schemes, and deselect every testapp option you see

Comment: You can find it in XCode **Product** menu > **Edit Scheme**