# Generate build without launching simulator in React Native

Tags: react-native, continuous-integration

I am using the following command to generate an iOS build in a CI environment:

```
react-native run-ios --configuration Release --no-packager
```

The problem is, this will launch the simulator. I am trying to avoid that as it is a CI machine. Is there a way to generate a build without launching the simulator?

Comment: Which environment are you using for your builds?  i.e. tfs has a prepare react-native-bundle and an xcode build task.

Comment: see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42117483/1471542

Comment: Without CI, i use xcode to build, and it never launces simulator. CI I'm not sure.