# How to create .ipa file for testing from react-native app for IOS using command line

Tags: ios, iphone, reactjs, react-native

I am using react-native version `0.57.7`. **How to create** `.ipa` file from `react-native app` **using command line**.

I followed some stack-overflow answers([as an example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52498639/4408364%60)) on how to create `.ipa` file from a react-native app so that I can install it in my Iphone and test it.

The answer's I found are either too old or do not have same directory structure as my react native app version `0.57.7`.

Could you please tell me how to generate `.ipa` file in `react-native` version `0.57.7` for testing it on iphone.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the provisioning profiles sorted then it is fairly straight forward. Though to be able to test it on device without it being plugged into the computer you will need either an `ad-hoc` or `enterprise` provisioning profile.

So you will need the provisioning profile and the [distribution certificate](https://support.magplus.com/hc/en-us/articles/203808748-iOS-Creating-a-Distribution-Certificate-and-p12-File) that you wish to install on your machine.

Basically you have two commands that you will need to run to create your ipa.

1. Create the archive.
2. Sign the archive. (this will create the ipa from the archive)

**Folder structure**

In the root directory for my application I have the following folders

- android
- app
- ios
- node_modules

So open a terminal in the root directory of the application and we can begin:

---

**Create the archive**

Now there are subtle differences if you use cocoapods or not. You can see the differences here in the two different commands notably that `project` is replaced by `workspace` and that `xcodeproj` is replaced by `xcworkspace`.

Choose the one that matches your setup best. The result will be a file called myawesomeapp.xcarchive in the root directory of your application.

**No Cocoapods/project**

```
xcodebuild "-project" "ios/myawesomeapp.xcodeproj" "-scheme" "myawesomeapp" "-configuration" "Release" "DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=YOUR_TEAM_ID" "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER=YOUR_TEAM_ID/myawesomeapp_profile_name" "archive" "-archivePath" "myawesomeapp.xcarchive"
```

**Cocoapods/workspace**

```
xcodebuild "-workspace" "ios/myawesomeapp.xcworkspace" "-scheme" "myawesomeapp" "-configuration" "Release" "DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=YOUR_TEAM_ID" "PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER=YOUR_TEAM_ID/myawesomeapp_profile_name" "archive" "-archivePath" "myawesomeapp.xcarchive"
```

I like to specify the `DEVELOPMENT_TEAM` and the `PROVISIONING_PROFILE_SPECIFIER` this is so that the correct provisioning profile is used for the app.

I choose the configuration option of `Release` as I personally use distribution profiles so that I can then pass the built ipa to the testing team.

If you haven't done anything fancy to your setup then you can probable just replace the words `myaewsomeapp` with the name of your application, and `myawesomeapp_profile_name` with the name of your provisioning profile.

---

**Sign the archive**

You have to sign the archive so that it will become an ipa. To that you need an `export_options.plist`.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
    <dict>
        <key>compileBitcode</key>
        <false/>
        <key>method</key>
        <string>ad-hoc</string>
        <key>provisioningProfiles</key>
        <dict>
            <key>com.myawesomeapp</key>
            <string>myawesomeapp_profile_name</string>
        </dict>
        <key>signingCertificate</key>
        <string>iPhone Distribution: NAME_OF_YOUR_SIGNING_CERTIFICATE (YOUR_TEAM_ID)</string>
        <key>teamID</key>
        <string>YOUR_TEAM_ID</string>
    </dict>
</plist>
```

So there are a few key points about this:

Set the method to match what your provisioning profile is for. If it is an ad-hoc profile then ad-hoc should go there. The options are app-store, ad-hoc, enterprise or development.

Change `com.myawesomeapp` to the bundle identifier of your application. Change `my_awesomeapp_profile_name` to be the name of your provisioning profile. Add the name of the signing certificate that you are using. Finally, add `YOUR_TEAM_ID`

Once you have created the export_options.plist and saved it in the root directory of your application you can then run the next command in the terminal:

`xcodebuild "-exportArchive" "-archivePath" "myawesomeapp.xcarchive" "-exportPath" "./" "-exportOptionsPlist" "export_options.plist"`

This will then sign the ipa for you and produce a few other files, you may prefer to write to a subdirectory in your application directory rather than the root.

Once you have your ipa you can then install it on your iPhone using Xcode.

---

As with everything, your setup may differ from mine. That being said this is the method that I use locally, and the method that I use on our CI. It works for us, hopefully it will help you create your ipa.

More information about building can be found at https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/technotes/tn2339/_index.html.

Although it is no longer updated, they go into more detail about what everything does and looking at the offical docs is a good place to start.

Comment: Is it possible to generate `.ipa` without signing. I need it for testing purpose only

Comment: No an ipa only come from signing the exported archive. You can install on the phone but it requires the phone to be connected to the development server so as soon as you phone loses connection from the that the application will stop functioning. https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/running-on-device this link shows you how to run on device.

Answer (score 0):

Andrew has the right answer, but if you are going to end up doing a lot of deployments, I would highly recommend using Fastlane. Once you learn fastlane, it will take a lot of the headaches away from the ios deployment process. I made a [youtube video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tgmgH055ZvM) on this that talks about the manual process and how fastlane makes it automates each step for you.

I hope this helps!