# How to check size of the react-native app in iOS and Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios

I need to check my app size and need to reduce the size if it is huge. Can anyone let me know how can I check the size in my simulator

Answer (score 1):

Rather than checking simulator size which is usually the debug APK, and debug APK are much larger and you wont be able to find the exact size.

Its better you create a release APK by `./gradlew assembleRelease` and it will give the approx size of your production APK. You can reduce it furher by creating AAB and other twitches like disabling proguard and enabling hermes etc.

Hope it helps.

Comment: How can I found the same for an ipa file for iOS app

Comment: for ios, ive usually checked after pushing to testflight and there downloading it. or you can check how to convert to ipa by his link https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110496/how-to-build-ipa-application-for-react-native-ios and check the size

Comment: Can I able to get the size in simulator itself. After converting to ipa how can I check the size.

Comment: simulator i dont believe, but after ipa shift that ipa in your mac, and in any folder you can check that size

Comment: did it help you @sejn?

Comment: I need to check.