# How to create a distributive react-native app for iOS?

Tags: ios, react-native

I have created a react-native app using the tools - VS Code, expo, react-native.

I am able to run the app on expo client as well as xcode simulator easily on my laptop. What I want now is to make a distributive file for iOS like we have .apk for androids for this app.

I referred to this question [How to build .ipa application for react-native-ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110496/how-to-build-ipa-application-for-react-native-ios)

and tried

```
react-native run-ios --configuration=release
```

but I get an error:

> Error iOS project folder not found. Are you sure this is a React Native project?

Don't know what I am missing here? I am a beginner with react-native, would really appreciate any help on this.

Answer (score 1):

You have to run `expo build:ios` that will then ask you your account and certificates, once you have all that figured out it will give you a link where you can see how the build is doing, after it's complete you can download the .ipa file and use the app transporter from the app store to send you app to apple servers.

(All this if you are using expo, if you aren't it's a hole different conversation and a lot more difficult)