# Where is the iOS build folder located for React Native apps?

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I have just built an iOS React Native app, but I can't locate the app or .ipa file.

Google doesn't seem to have many answers and in Xcode, the folder is just labelled as 'build'.

I need to upload the .ipa file to Microsoft App Center. Where should I look for the app?

#### Update

I found this: [How to build .ipa application for react-native-ios?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110496/how-to-build-ipa-application-for-react-native-ios)

Seems like they missed some bits out int the RN docs!

Comment: Are you on `Expo Magaed` project?? did you use `expo build` to build app??

Comment: Thanks - figured it out!