# How to build iOS app in expo without login access?

Tags: react-native, expo

I don’t have access to apple developer account.
but I have the p12 distribution and mobile provisional certificates from the client.

When I try to create ios app with expo cli without login:

1. It ask me the password for the certificate. There’s no password set
   on the certificate how can I give a blank input?
2. Then it ask for apple team ID (from where can I get it?)
3. I also want to know what else are required to build app without login.

There’s no documentation or resources available on the expo site for it.

Answer (score 1):

As far as i know , getting build versions for ios apps without apple developer account is not possible.
although , this article might be helpful[check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42110496/how-to-build-ipa-application-for-react-native-ios)